# How to find last row that ran NULLIF() or has null in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, nullif

I currently run this operation to convert empty strings to null. Is any way to find out the last row that has gone through NULLIF() operation or has null character so I can process everything from that point. My table has a timestamp column. I have 150 columns like recovery_email and I'd like to start from the last empty string was found in either of them.

```
UPDATE table                                                                                                 
    SET recovery_email = NULLIF(recovery_email, ''), # There are 150 columns like recovery_email.
    email = NULLIF(email, ''),
    WHERE timestamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

Why would you use `NULLIF()`?  Just filter down to the rows you want:

```
UPDATE table                                                                                                 
    SET recovery_email = NULL                                
    WHERE timestamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND recovery_email = '';
```

You can put an index on `recovery_email` and not worry about attempting to filter by time.

Or, better yet, defined the column with a `check` constraint (in the most recent versions of MySQL) so empty strings are not allowed.

Comment: sorry for a new update, I should have clarified that there are 150 columns like recovery email

Answer (score 0):

If none of your `recovery_email` is `null` before the `update` query is executed, you can run the following query after the  `update` statement to get the `timestamp` of the last updated row:

```
select max(timestamp) last_timestamp 
from mytable 
where recovery_email is null and timestamp >= now() - interval 1 day
```

Otherwise, you need to compute the latest value *before* the `update`, with the following query:

```
select max(timestamp) last_timestamp 
from mytable 
where recovery_email = '' and timestamp >= now() - interval 1 day
```

Comment: sorry for a new update, I should have clarified that there are 150 columns like recovery email